# Warning in Google Console due to invalid items in Struture data

Tags: google-search-console, search-engines, structured-data, json-ld

I have added Structured data for sporting event on website and this page started showing `5 valid items detected: All have warnings` as i have five items in the structured data on Google Console (URL Inspection)

Warning is due to two optional fields even though this JSON LD data is validated

- Missing field "performer" (optional)
- Missing field "offers" (optional)

[image]

Is there a way i can fix these warning?

Is this going to effect page ranking or its not good in any form as warning is for optional fields but still showing. should i ignore it?

These items are not showing in google search as this was updated 8-10 weeks before so i wanted to give it some time to see if it will show even though its not guaranteed by Google. Can i do something from my side to improve chances of this showing in search

Comment: Found possible reply https://www.infidigit.com/news/structured-data-warnings/.. will keep question open just in case i get tips to improve or a possible fix/solution

Answer (score 2):

If a field is not applicable to your entity, then the warnings are generally speaking safe to ignore. It is unlikely to impact your visibility in search results.

Sometimes this could be a signal that there is a more appropriate schema to use, but even then there may still be fields that don't apply.